# Disable jQuery Masonry

Tags: jquery-masonry

I'm trying to disable [jQuery masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) for certain states of a page on my site but can't seem to find a way to do it. Do you know how I could do this?  Thanks.

Comment: The Masonry plugin author, David Desandro has made a `.masonry( 'destroy' )` [Codepen function example](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/Ewmak) -

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the list of methods
http://desandro.github.io/masonry/docs/methods.html#content

Assuming your Masonry container ID is #masonry

```
$('#masonry').masonry( 'destroy' );
```

Answer (score 2):

I used @kaverzniy's answer but wrapped it in

```
var container = $('#container'); // or whatever your container is
if(container.masonry()) {
    $('#masonry').masonry( 'destroy' );
}
```

to avoid calling methods on masonry prior to initialization (in case it hadn't been initialized yet).